# Mean square displacement of data

Tags: list-manipulation

In my data set I have time, x-position, y-position. I want to calculate mean square displacement. i am new here I tried some but it shows error in code please see below:

```
d1 = Import["data.xlsx"][[1]];

(* dr=Take[d1,{1,25}]; *)

da = d1[[All, {1, 2}]];
db = d1[[All, {1, 3}]];
t = First /@ da;
x = Last /@ da;
y = Last /@ db;

r = 0; n = 4; a = n/2;
For[i = 1, i <= a, cnt = 1; 
  For[j = i, j <= i + n/2, dx[i] = x[[i]] - x[[j]]; 
    dy[i] = y[[i]] - y[[j]];
    Print[dx]
    (*s=((dx)^2)+((dy)^2);*)
    r += ((dx[i])^2) + ((dy[i])^2); j++]
  Print[i, " " , r];
  i++]

data is here:
0.00E+00    9.67E+00    1.87E+01
8.70E-03    9.33E+00    3.10E+00
1.74E-02    9.85E+00    4.53E+00
2.61E-02    9.87E+00    4.57E+00
3.48E-02    1.00E+01    4.96E+00
4.35E-02    9.69E+00    4.63E+00
5.22E-02    9.78E+00    4.65E+00
6.09E-02    9.69E+00    4.60E+00
6.96E-02    9.60E+00    4.57E+00
7.83E-02    9.72E+00    4.72E+00
8.70E-02    9.80E+00    4.78E+00
9.57E-02    9.78E+00    4.83E+00
1.04E-01    9.75E+00    4.75E+00
1.13E-01    9.68E+00    4.60E+00
1.22E-01    9.66E+00    4.65E+00
1.31E-01    9.66E+00    4.63E+00
1.39E-01    9.67E+00    4.64E+00
1.48E-01    9.71E+00    4.76E+00
1.57E-01    9.80E+00    4.76E+00
1.65E-01    9.67E+00    4.66E+00
1.74E-01    9.71E+00    4.63E+00
1.83E-01    9.67E+00    4.69E+00
1.91E-01    9.70E+00    4.68E+00
2.00E-01    9.75E+00    4.78E+00
2.09E-01    9.72E+00    4.72E+00
2.18E-01    9.76E+00    4.75E+00
2.26E-01    9.72E+00    4.72E+00
2.35E-01    9.86E+00    4.85E+00
2.44E-01    9.68E+00    4.58E+00
```

here first column is time second is x and third is y. after that i want to take mean square of first 10 then next 10 and so on to get a constant  value. I don't know how to do this so can you please help me to do this problem.

Comment: Where is your Excel file? Consider converting it to *.csv and posting it on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/). Otherwise, please look up `Differences[]` and `Norm[]`.

Comment: instead of excel file I put my data below the code.

Comment: The syntax of your `For` expressions is invalid.

Comment: if I will plot i and r then it should be kind of straight line. For that n=Length[t;]

Comment: could you please explain me this Sow[{i,r}]]][[2,1]] command??

Comment: If I want to export the data in excel file then how can I do that??

Comment: `r=0; n=Length[t]; ir=Table[{i,r+=Sum[(x[[i]]-x[[j]])^2+(y[[i]]-y[[j]])^2, {j,i,i+n/2}]}, {i,1,n/2}]; Print[ListPlot[ir]]; Export["ir.xlsx", ir]`